# Code inside loops wont print

Tags: c++, arrays, graph, cout

```
void Graph::sortW ()
{
    int length = vertices*vertices; 
    int array[length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
        cout << array[i]; // nothing prints 
    }
    cout << "i";     
    // convert to 1D array 
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vertices; j++) {
            array[i*vertices+j] = matrix[i][j]; 
            cout << array[i*vertices+j] << " "; // nothing prints 
        } 
    }
    cout << "j"; 
    qsort(array, length, sizeof(int), compare); 

    //  for (int i=0 ; i<25; i++)
    //      cout << array[i] << endl;  // only loop that prints?! 
}
```

I have no idea why the output is `ij` only. Sort is called in the constructor like so:

```
// Sort weights using qsort 
sortW();
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `int array[length];` is not standard C++. You should also use `std::sort` instead of `qsort`.

Comment: You didn't say how `vertices` was set. I bet it's `0`.

Comment: If it's not printing `array` entries, then the loop termination condition must be `false` - i.e. `0 < length` is false because `length <= 0`, which means `vertices` must be 0... why not add a `std::cout << "vertices " << vertices << '\n';` up the top so you can check?  Basic debugging skill....

Comment: i have used vertices throughout the entire program, its set to be 5. and im sure its >0

Comment: Alright, Ill try flushing the output.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg if the output was buffered, "ij" wouldn't have shown up...

Comment: Where do you declare `vertices`? Where do you initialize it? Please *update your question* to include more code showing that. I'll bet that `vertices` is a member variable, and you haven't initialized it yet before calling `sortW`.

Comment: Yes, I tried it again, this time printing out vertices and the result is that vertices somehow is 0 even though at the beginning of the constructor, i set it for 5 for testing. Ill have to see why/how it changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you put a

```
cout << vertices;
```

at the beginning of your function. My guess ist that `vertices` is zero?

Comment: I did have vertices printed out in a different call, and its 5.

Comment: @Ashley Print it in *this* function to make sure.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and check again. Also try to step through the function using the debugger.